# Excel formula to sum numbers that match two conditions recorded horizontally row after row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

[image: Image of the excel data]

I have a dataset given as the attached image.  I am trying to sum the number of people that match two conditions recorded horizontally row after row(Contract type, Employee Group). For example in cell C13, I am trying to get the total number of people that are Official and are in the A group. What formula would be appropriate?
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$F$7*($C$3:$F$3=C$12)*($C$2:$F$2=$B13))
```

[image]

Comment: Dang, you must take lessons from Scott Craner.  You are answering the question while I am still reading it. 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd - I gotta get faster, Scott is the best.

Comment: Try the oldest trick in the book..."Looketh over there!"  While he looketh, you post your answer!

Comment: It also helps that I am on vacation this week. And just scanning when sitting. :) @ForwardEd